# Ionic - how to open URL in system browser

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

How can I open URL in an ionic application?

Answer (score 1):

No need to install In App Browser plugin. Simply do

```
window.open(url, '_system');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install

```
cordova plugin add inappbrowser
```

then you can use

```
window.open(URL,'_system','location=yes'),!1;
```

which will open the **URL** in system browser

Comment: garuraj i want to launch this <a class="button" href="{{item.url}}" >Click </a> in browser

Comment: @luffy you can bind window.open to an onclick event inline.
`<a class='button' href='{{item.url}}' onclick="window.open(this.href, '_system', 'location=yes'),!1"> Click </a>`